# Mysql query not giving the two rows with max numbers

Tags: mysql

I have query :-

```
select
  CustomerName,
  Scenario,
  StepNo,
  InTransit,
  IsAlef,
  RunNo,
  count(1) as Total
from RequestInfo
group by CustomerName,
  Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,
  IsAlef,RunNo
order by Total DESC LIMIT 1;
```

which gives me output :-

```
+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| CustomerName | Scenario    | StepNo | InTransit | IsAlef | RunNo | Total |
+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
| MMT          | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 2     |   226 |
+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+
```

the actual table is :-

```
+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+
| CustomerName | Scenario    | StepNo | InTransit | IsAlef | RunNo | count(1) |
+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+
| MMT          | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 1     |      206 |
| MMT          | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 2     |      226 |
| MMT          | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 3     |      206 |
| YATRA        | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 1     |      298 |
| YATRA        | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 2     |      206 |
| YATRA        | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 3     |      147 |
+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+
```

but i want output like below:-

```
+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+
| CustomerName | Scenario    | StepNo | InTransit | IsAlef | RunNo | count(1) |
+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+
| MMT          | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 2     |      226 |
| YATRA        | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 1     |      298 |
+--------------+-------------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+----------+
```

The idea is to get the rows with max count numbers of the last column "Total".

Comment: what's the actual table again? count(1) seems like generated data

Comment: Please show your source table's data.

Comment: well count(1) column is generated data through this query :- select CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo, count(1) from RequestInfo group by CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo;

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query

```
select a.* from RequestInfo  a,
(select CustomerName,max(Total) as total from RequestInfo  group by CustomerName ) b
where a.customername=b.customername
and a.total=b.total;
```

Comment: getting error "  ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Total' in 'field list'
"

Comment: what is the column name in table which has count data?

Comment: its count(1). well count(1) column is generated data through this query :- select CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo, count(1) from RequestInfo group by CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo;

Comment: try this one ..
select a.* from RequestInfo  a,
(select CustomerName,count(1)  as total from RequestInfo  group by CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo ) b
where a.customername=b.customername
and a.total=b.total;

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'a.total' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Just set your 'TOTAL DESC LIMIT' as '2'

```
SELECT   CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo, count(1) AS      
Total FROM RequestInfo GROUP BY 
CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo ORDER BY Total DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: This query will actually works.You just need to change your 'DESC LIMIT' as '2' instead of '1'. Just execute this query as it is

Comment: what happens on a third `CustomerName`? ;)

Comment: i m getting this                                                                                                            | MMT          | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 2     |   226 |
| MMT          | HotelBrowse | 1      | No        | No     | 1     |   206 |

Comment: Actually we won't worry about the third `CustomerName` and so on......        Her requirement is to get                                                                           `MMT          HotelBrowse  1       No        No     2        226
 YATRA         HotelBrowse  1      No        No     1         298`
 For this the above query works well                                                    **Demo** [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/612386/2

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'count(1)' in 'field list'

Comment: Just remove the quotes(') for count(1).

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

```
         select R1.*  from RequestInfo R1
         inner join 
         (
         select CustomerName,MAX( `count(1)`)  `count(1)`  
         from RequestInfo
         group by CustomerName
         )R2 on R1.CustomerName=R2.CustomerName and R1.`count(1)`=R2.`count(1)`
```

Demo : [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25016d/2/0)

Comment: i m getting ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'count(1)' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

error because **count** is reserved keyword in mysql so you can write between `count(1)` not only count without acute 
your query like this

```
select CustomerName,Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,RunNo,`count(1)` as Total from customer group by CustomerName;
```

[check here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa833/1)

Comment: still i m getting results only for MMT and not YATRA with "Desc Limit 2". The query should give results based on different Customer Name and only the row which has max counts.

Comment: well this time i did get MMT & YATRA but the the last column got sumed up,  i only want the rows which have max count distinguished by the CustomerName and RunNo.